# How to open the same directory in another panel in Midnight Commander?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mc, panel

In Midnight Commander, how to quickly set the right panel to the same directory as the left panel (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Newer versions of Midnight Commander use Alt-o (also ESC followed by o) to do this.

Older versions used Alt-o for doing a change directory to the currently highlighted directory, so it will depend on which build you are using.

Comment: Version 4.8.3 (at least) now uses `Alt-i` to switch the other panel to the same folder as the current panel. See `man mc` for more.

Comment: on one of my machines (Version 4.8.29) alt-o doesn't work, but Esc-o works, to load the currently selected directory to the second panel (despite being said in man)

Answer (score 129):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> opens the directory your cursor is on.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> opens the active panel's directory on the other panel.

Tested on MC 4.7

Comment: For MacOS the keys are`Ctrl` + `O`, `Ctrl` + `I`

Answer (score 18):

For me in iTerm2 the <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> (First 
press <kbd>esc</kbd> and after press <kbd>i</kbd> not in the same time) is working well on my mac,

Comment: Works fine on other Mac terminals, like KiTTY.

Comment: Xshell and other related terminals couldnt give respond to `alt´ key, since its surpressing its own shell. Good solution.

Comment: This also works for me

Answer (score 1):

For os x terminal:

Press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, you will see 'Option is Meta'.

Now <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically combination is <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. Some OS installations and probably some terminals have different settings regarding <kbd>Meta</kbd> key. On all my machines it is <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but I've heard from colleagues that they have it mapped to <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd> key.